# Necessary and sufficient conditions for some inequalities to hold

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Take the real numbers $c,d,e,f,g,h$.

Are the following two assertions true:

(1) $c\geq f+h$ if and only if there exists $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $c\geq a+b$, $f\leq a$, $h\leq b$.

(2) $d\leq e+g$ if and only if there exists $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $d\leq a+b$, $e\geq a$, $f\geq b$.

Comment: For $(1)$ pick $a=f, b=h$. Similarly for $(2)$.

Comment: Are you suggesting a counterexample or are you confirming that 1-2 hold? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1):

$(\implies)$ Set $a=f$ and $b=h$. Since $c\geq f+h$, $f\leq f$, and $h\leq h$, the claim holds.
$(\impliedby)$ Since $f\leq a$ and $h\leq b$ we have, $f+h\leq a+b$. Hence, $c\geq a+b\geq f+h$.

For (2), it is proven similarly.